# Javascript promise then inside a class

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to understand how Promises are working and I can't get my piece of code to work.

```
class Lights {
    constructor(delay) {
        this.blue = 0;
        this.green = 0;
        this.red = 0;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    fadeIn(color, i) {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self[color] = i;
                console.log(self[color]);
                i+=5;
                if (i <= 255) {
                    self.fadeIn(color, i);
                }
                resolve(self);
            }, self.delay);
        });
    }

    fadeOut(color, i) {
        var self = this;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                self[color] = i;
                console.log(self[color]);
                i-=5;
                if (i >= 0) {
                    self.fadeIn(color, i);
                }
                resolve(self);
            }, self.delay);
        });
    }
}


var lights = new Lights(50);

lights.fadeIn("blue", 0).then(
    lights.fadeOut("blue", 255)
);
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ntcbk74p/) of the code.

The idea behind the code is to set the blue color from 0 to 255 and `Then` from 255 to 0. How can I do this ?

Comment: `lights.fadeIn("blue", 0).then(() => lights.fadeOut("blue", 255));`  Otherwise your fadeout will execute before your promise is resolved.

Comment: Just to clarify, your `then` expects a function to call when it is finished, but what you are doing is executing the `fadeOut` and passing back the promise from that, so it gets executed before it's suppose to.

Comment: Adding to previous comments; your `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods are not waiting until the fade is completed to resolve the promise, so the `fadeOut` will start running before `fadeIn` completes. Try replacing `self.fadeIn(color, i);` with `return resolve(self.fadeIn(color, i));`, same applies for `fadeOut` method.

Comment: Also note that you are calling `fadeIn` from your `fadeOut` method, probably not what you want. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/87haj6x9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making recursive calls so on the last call what you resolve is not the resolve in your first promise that you call `then` on so you could store that first resolve in one property in your class and then call it.

```js
class Lights {
  constructor(delay) {
    this.blue = 0;
    this.green = 0;
    this.red = 0;
    this.delay = delay;
    this.fadeInResolve = null;
    this.fadeOutResolve = null;
  }

  fadeIn(color, i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.fadeInResolve) {
        this.fadeInResolve = resolve
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        this[color] = i;
        console.log(this[color]);
        i += 5;
        if (i <= 255) this.fadeIn(color, i);
        else this.fadeInResolve(this)
      }, this.delay);
    });
  }

  fadeOut(color, i) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (!this.fadeOutResolve) {
        this.fadeOutResolve = resolve
      }

      setTimeout(() => {
        this[color] = i;
        console.log(this[color]);
        i -= 5;
        if (i >= 0) this.fadeOut(color, i);
        else this.fadeOutResolve(this)
      }, this.delay);
    });
  }
}


var lights = new Lights(50);

lights.fadeIn("blue", 0).then(() => {
  console.log('Fade in done')
  lights.fadeOut("blue", 255).then(() => {
    console.log('Fade out done')
  })
});
```

Comment: I used your piece of code to make [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hjx1az4n/). I tried to do one fadein, then one fadeout, then again a fadein with a different color and finally a fadeout. But the fadeout is never launched, can you tell me why ?

Comment: Because you should set it to null after it's resolved, also you could use async/await instead of all those then's https://jsfiddle.net/hjx1az4n/1/

Comment: Is it possible, inside the await, to launch two fadeIn (which can resolve at different time, wait for the two to resolve and then make another action ?

Comment: Sure https://jsfiddle.net/hjx1az4n/3/, but you need to set up different properties for each color

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was super helpful

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.prototype.then()` should take a callback function and the recursion is not waiting. Consider this code which can be used to do the same thing:

```js
//promisify :)
function timer(delay) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            resolve();
        }, delay);
    });
}

class _Modulator {
    constructor(_resolution = 255, _delay = 5) {
        /* assert resolution and delay > 0; */

        this._resolution = _resolution;
        this._delay = _delay;

        this._counter = 0;
        this._running = false;
    }

    start() {
        console.log("timer start");
        this._running = true;
        this._start();
    }

    _start() {
        return timer(this._delay).then(() => {
            if (this._running === true) {
                this._counter += 1;

                console.log("tick");
                this._onTick();

                /* care should be taken to ensure this will always catch, e.g., 
                 * correcting init
                 */
                if (this._counter === this._resolution) {
                    this._counter = 0;
                    this._onCycle();
                }

                this._start();
            }
        });
    }

    stop() {
        this._running = false;
        console.log("timer stopped");
    }

    _onTick() {
        console.log("tick handle: %s", this._counter);
    }

    _onCycle() {
        console.log("new cycle");
    }
}

class UpDownModulator extends _Modulator {
    constructor(_resolution = 255, _delay = 5) {
        super(_resolution, _delay);
        this._dir = 1;
    }

    _onTick() {
        console.log("tick handle: %s", this.getCounter());
    }

    _onCycle() {
        this._toggleDirection();
        console.log("new cycle: going %s", this.getDirection());
    }

    _toggleDirection() {
        this._dir ^= 1; 
    }

    getCounter() {
        return this._dir
            ? this._counter
            : this._resolution - this._counter;
    }

    getDirection() {
        return this._dir ? "up" : "down";
    }
}

let c = new UpDownModulator();

c.start();
```

You can create a ColorFader class that depends on a Modulator and observe it. This creates clean abstractions that adhere to SRP.

I hope this helps!